How does this assembly code perform the source code b = a/3 when a = 2?
I'm trying to trace this C source code (when a = 2):
b = a/3;

To this ARM assembly code (for unsigned 1 byte value):
ldrb    r2, [fp, #-6]   @ zero_extendqisi2  @ tmp162, a
ldr r3, .L34    @ tmp164,
umull   r1, r3, r2, r3  @, tmp163, tmp162, tmp164
mov r3, r3, lsr #1  @ tmp161, tmp163,
strb    r3, [fp, #-5]   @ tmp165, b

And this ARM assembly code (for unsigned 2 bytes value):
ldrsh   r3, [fp, #-8]   @ tmp185, a
ldr r2, .L51    @ tmp187,
smull   r0, r2, r3, r2  @, tmp186, tmp185, tmp187
mov r3, r3, asr #31 @ tmp188, tmp185,
rsb r3, r3, r2  @ tmp184, tmp188, tmp186
strh    r3, [fp, #-6]   @ movhi @ tmp184, b

I don't understand how these are possibly getting the correct answer. What value does a label hold? Its position on the program counter or something else entirely?

The instruction ldr r3, .L34 loads a word of data from label .L34.  Check what is found at that label.  This looks like typical code for division through multiplication with the reciprocal (see this question).

So I'm assuming the value of .L17 comes from the line below it: .word -1431655765. Seems my answer is that division and modulo by a constant is not traceable to source code and I need to learn reciprocal multiplication.

Note that that's just 0xaaaaaaab, i.e. 2^33/3.  If you trace the code, it should be easy to figure out how it works.

No, it's actually 2^32/1.5 hence the mov r3, r3, lsr #1

@Jester Right, missed that when I checked the result.

Didn't you learn "reciprocal multiplication" in high school algebra? It's basically a/3 == a * 1/3

Well yes I just mean reciprocal multiplication as it relates to fixed point fractions and fixed point arithmetic. I've never seen or heard of this before. Like the 1 byte division does a logical shift right 1 time on the quotient and 2 bytes does an arithmetic shift right 31 times on the divisor and then reverse subtracts the quotient by the divisor. I need to do research and learn what's going on there cause it doesn't make any sense to me rn.

Read Labor of Division if you are interested in the details.

Eureka! I finally understand what's going on. Thank you all for all your help and resources.
